# Как узнать, какой используется штрифт в psd макете, открытом в Adobe Fireworks?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Сейчас верстаю макет для этого [сайта](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/). Макет открываю с помощью Adobe Fireworks. Когда кликаю мышкой на текст поле шрифта пустое. Как мне узнать, каким шрифтом написан тот или иной текст? Дизайнер прислал в архиве кучу шрифтов.

Comment: Верстальщики помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: шрифты установил в ОС?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-find-font-name-in-fireworks-when-font-not-installed